# How to render multiple view page in single page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

First see the small code snippet.
We can  render multiple view page in a single page based on requirement.Here One div(id=d1) is there. When Button(1) is clicked after ajax call it put one more button(2) with another div(id=2). When button2 is clicked dynamic content is set in the next view and in a single page two view is showen. For that we can use .html() with the id of the div.

But I want to achieve it using AngularJs. As in AngularJs has only one view so I am getting confused where and how to get two view in same page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="b1" value="Button1"> 

        <div id="d1"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#b1").on("click",function(){
                    ajaxFunc("url1",{data},function(){
                        $("#d1").html('<input type="button" id="b2" value="Button2"><div id="d2"></div>');
                    });
                });

                $("#b2").on("click",function(){
                    ajaxFunc("url2",{data},function(){
                        $("#d2").html('This is div');
                    });
                });
            });

            function ajaxFunc(url,data,callback){
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    data:data,
                    success:function(resp){
                        if(callback){
                            callback();
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look at Ui.Router https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: here some more explicit doc : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views